# Android Display and save data in next tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter

I have created a `FragmentActivity` of 2 tabs. This is a very basic `Tab` example from Android Developer tutorial using `FragmentActivity` and `FragmentPagerAdapter` [Code Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html)

```
    public class FragmentPagerSupport extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {
        SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
        static final int NUM_ITEMS = 10;
        ViewPager mViewPager;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.fragment_pager);
            final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
                    ...........
            }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            Bundle args = new Bundle();         
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new Fragment01();
                args.putInt(Fragment01.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
                fragment.setArguments(args);
            break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new Fragment02();
                args.putInt(Fragment02.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
                fragment.setArguments(args);
            break;
                    return fragment;
               }
           }
```

Then I have created 2 different `fragments` for 2 `tabs`:

```
public static class Fragment01 extends Fragment {
    private EditText mName; 
    private EditText mEmail1;
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "2";

    public Fragment01() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_customer_add, container, false);
            mName = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.customer_add_name);
            mEmail = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.customer_add_email);
                    View confirmButton = v.findViewById(R.id.customer_add_button);

                    confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
            ......................
                             }
            });
     }
  }
```

Now in the 2nd tab I need to show the input value of `Name` and `Email` from 1st tab and on confirm from 2nd tab need to save in `database`. But here I stuck. I am not getting an idea how I can keep data from `first tab`? Please help.

Comment: you can use SharedPreference to save values it is very easy

http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html

check this link

Comment: Have a look at this: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach could be to use **Singleton** DP. There will be only one object having Name, Email etc. as fields. Set Name and Email fields using setters when you are in first fragment and access them using getters in second fragment.

On confirm, you can insert entire object into database.